# Is any representation of a finite group defined over the algebraic integers?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, gr.group-theory

Apologies in advance if this is obvious.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not obvious...my guess is there isn't, but I can't think of any counterexamples right off the bat.

Comment: So you are asking if there exist a basis for every GIVEN finite subgroup, not one basis that works for every finite subgroup, right? Coz then the answer is no.

Comment: Yes, any particular subgroup.

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is the same as the previous one. The subset of GL_n(\bar{Q}) consisting of matrices with algebraic integer entries (which is not a subgroup), is different from GL_n of the algebraic integers.

Comment: The subset of GL_n(\bar{Q}) consisting of matrices such that the matrix AND its inverse have algebraic integer entries is a subgroup, and obviously a group representation with algebraic integer entries would have to land there.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_is_realizable_over_principal_ideal_domain_iff_it_is_realizable_over_field_of_fractions

Unfortunately, not every ring of algebraic integers (or even cyclotomic integers) is a PID.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Not a satisfying argument: We can, first of all, find a basis in which the entries lie in some algebraic number field $K$. Let $\mathcal{O}$ be the ring of integers of $K$.
Then there is a locally free $\mathcal{O}$-module $M$ of rank $n$ preserved by $G$: add up all the translates of $\mathcal{O}^n$ under $G$. Now, $M$ need not itself be free,  but it is isomorphic
as an $\mathcal{O}$-module to the sum of various ideals of $\mathcal{O}$. Now pass to an extension $L/K$ so that every ideal class of $K$ trivializes in $L$, e.g. the Hilbert class field; then $G$ preserves a free rank $n$ module
for the ring of integers of $L$.   Sorry!

Answer (score 17):

This is not really an answer, but is too long for a comment. The proof given by Moonface above is given in more or less that form in the 1962 book of Curtis and Reiner. As far as I know, it is still open whether all irreducible representations of a finite group $G$ can be realized over 
$\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$, where $\omega$ is a complex primitive $|G|$-th roots of unity, though I think the paper of Cliff,Ritter and Weiss settles the questions for finite solvable groups. The paper
of Serre ( the three letters to Feit) give counterexamples to a slightly different question:
they show (among other things) that a representation of a finite group can be realised over 
some number fields, but might not be able to be realised over the ring of algebraic integers
of that field. Brauer's characterization of characters/Brauer's induction theorem show that 
all representations of the finite group $G$ may be realised over $\mathbb{Q}[\omega]$ for 
$\omega$ as above ( $|G|$ can be replaced by the exponent of $G$ if desired). As I said, 
realizability over $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ is a different matter.

Answer (score 9):

By the way, [this paper](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1155753) may be of interest. It shows that for solvable groups, one doesn't have to do the Hilbert class extension moonface suggests, but for some non-solvable ones you do.  Also [this one](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2381795) has more examples.

Answer (score 7):

I just stumbled across this ancient question, and I want to point out my [notes](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Eandyp/notes/RepMatrixAlgebraic.pdf) here that prove the result in question.  The proof is basically the same as moonface's accepted answer, but with two improvements: 1. I give a very soft proof that all representations can be defined over some number field; and 2. instead of invoking the Hilbert class field to trivialize all ideals, I give an elementary argument to show you can pass to an extension trivializing the finite collection of them needed for this proof.

Sorry for bumping such an old question, but the above did not quite fit into a comment.